# How to install Windows live essential mail

Tags: wine, mail

How do I install Windows live essential mail on ubuntu? I want this because thunderbird and other clients fetch email every 5 mins, not instantly. 
Thanks.

Comment: if you can set it to 1 minutes manually, would you reconsider thunderbird or Evolution. :)

Comment: Microsoft makes closed software for Windows. `Windows` live essential is for windows and not for Ubuntu. TB can at minumum be set at 1 minute. Anything less is not advisable: you get into trouble if the mail being fetched is still being fetched when that minute is done.

Comment: Or if you insist on "instant" email receive, use a web based email client such as Gmail, which checks mail *very* frequently.

Answer (score 4):

Thunderbird, when using POP, checks mail as often as you tell it to.  That said, you don't want to be connecting to a POP server and checking email more often than about 5 minutes in most cases.  Each time requires the server to create a connection, check your login credentials, then check the mailbox for new mail.  This is not instant messaging, it is email. If you check too often, your email provider may complain.  It's like a little kid asking "are we there yet?" every few seconds.

Thunderbird can also use IMAP.  Depending on the provider, this has the ability for the server to push email to you rather than you checking for it.  I use gmail, and have Thunderbird set to check every 15 minutes.  But I get mail much more often than that.  I believe I get the mail as soon as it is available.

Microsoft mail does not have any abilities lacking in Thunderbird.  It is possible that if you use their email server and their email program, they can do whatever they want, but probably not.  Why would they?

Answer (score 0):

Use amsn for Ubuntu. It seems it informs instantly about new emails in Inbox. But not new emails in Junk or other folders in hotmail.